# ClusterManager onMarkerClickListener for non-clustered markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I am using Google Maps in Android with about 800 markers that I want to cluster and 80 markers that I do not want to cluster.

For the markers that I want to cluster, I add to the clusterManager using

```
mClusterManager.addItem(annotation);
```

For the markers that I do not want to cluster, I add them directly to the markerCollection

```
Marker marker = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().addMarker(annotation.getMarkerOptions());
```

Here `annoation` refers to an instance of AirMapMarker which is a custom class that implements `ClusterItem`

`annotation` contains a custom information such as identification string that I need to use when user taps on the marker.

The problem is, I cannot register onClickListener for both the cluster and the mapMarker. If I do, only map's onMarkerClickListener fires.

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
  public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // Handle marker click fires correctly.
  }
}

mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<AirMapMarker>(){
  public boolean onClusterItemClick(AirMapMarker marker) {
    // Doesn't Fire
  }
}
```

Now the problem is, inside onMarkerClick, I need access to identification which is part of AirMapMarker, in the case if the marker click happened on a single unclustered marker. I could not figure out a way to map `Marker` to `AirMapMarker` inside `onMarkerClick`.

I also tried completely removing `map.setOnMarkerClickListener` and rely only on `mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener`. However, now the problem is that when the marker click happens on markers that are not part of the cluster, `onClusterItemClick` fires with parameter `null`. This is because when adding marker to the map, you provide markerOptions and not ClusterItem object.

There is option inside ClusterManager to turn off clustering but this happens globally and not for a particular markers.

Anyone help me out or give me suggestions on what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question right. But here is a possible solution.

The markers you want to cluster, you can add them to the ClusterManager. 
`clusterManager.addItem(yourItem);`

The ones you don't want to cluster, you can add them directly to your GoogleMap object.
`map.addMarker`

Inside your MarkerRenderer you can override

`protected void onClusterItemRendered(YourClusterItem clusterItem, Marker marker)`

and map yourClusterItem to your Marker if needed. Or you can set a tag to your marker indicating it's a clusterItem.

In `public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)`
you can check your tag (or your map) to have a different behaviour for each kind of marker.